# Why button isn't found js

Tags: javascript

i cannot understand why button selection doesn't work, it always logs the "not working" thanks in advance!
this is the html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="register-style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="desktop-only">You will receive an email to confirm</p>
        <div class="form1">
            <form>
                <label for="fname">Email:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="something@gmail.com"><br>
                <label for="lname">Password:</label><br>
                <input type="password" id="lname" name="lname" value="">
                <label for="lname">Confirm password:</label><br>
                <input type="password" id="lname2" name="lname" value="">
                <br>
                <label for="fname">Phone number:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="07229169931"><br>
                <br>
                </form>
                <button id="cantgethim">Register</button>
                <script src="doge-register.js" ></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the js:

```
let buton = document.querySelector('#cantgethim')
if(buton)
buton.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
else
console.error("not working");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works

```js
function myFunction()
 {
  console.log("OK")
 }
 
let buton = document.getElementById('cantgethim')

if (buton) {
  buton.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}
else {
  console.error("not working");
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="register-style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="desktop-only">You will receive an email to confirm</p>
        <div class="form1">
            <form>
                <label for="fname">Email:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="something@gmail.com"><br>
                <label for="lname">Password:</label><br>
                <input type="password" id="lname" name="lname" value="">
                <label for="lname">Confirm password:</label><br>
                <input type="password" id="lname2" name="lname" value="">
                <br>
                <label for="fname">Phone number:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="07229169931"><br>
                <br>
                </form>
                <button id="cantgethim">Register</button>
                <script src="doge-register.js" ></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! so the problem is coming from another place

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `getElementById`

```js
let buton = document.getElementById(`cantgethim`);
```

This will select (like it sais) the element by the Id